# Cannot stop Fused Location Provider using removeLocationUpdates()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fusedlocation

I have an activity that is receiving the user location every X seconds. When the user location is within the radius of 15 meters from a specific point, I want the Location Provider to stop updating the user location and to start a new activity.

I have the following method to stop location updates:

```
private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
}
```

I call `stopLocationUpdates()` in both `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods. I've tried to call it inside the `for each` location cicle, when the case `distance < 15` is verified. None of this seems to work.

I am trying to call `finish()` to finish the current activity and by using the Logcat I see that the location keeps updating, although the activity is finished.
Plus, the new activity (`ExerciseActivity`) keeps launching in loop.
Please, let me know how I can stop this. Thank you in advance.

I leave here the major parts of the code of this activity:

```
class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val requestPermissionsRequestCode = 1
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
private var allCheckpoints: List<CheckpointResult> = ArrayList()
private val mAdapterNextCheckpoints = NextCheckpointAdapter()
private var nextCheckpoints: ArrayList<CheckpointResult> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)

    requestPermissionsIfNecessary(arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
    ))

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                mUserMarker.position = GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                mUserMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM)
                mUserMarker.title = getString(R.string.your_position)
                map.overlays.add(mUserMarker)
                map.controller.setCenter(mUserMarker.position)
            }
        }
    startLocationUpdates()
}

private fun startLocationUpdates() {
    locationRequest = create()
    locationRequest.interval = 4000
    locationRequest.priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                mUserMarker.position = GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                mUserMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM)
                mUserMarker.title = getString(R.string.your_position)
                map.overlays.add(mUserMarker)
                mAdapterNextCheckpoints

                if (nextCheckpoints.isNotEmpty()) {
                    for (checkpoint in nextCheckpoints) {
                        val results = FloatArray(3)
                        Location.distanceBetween(checkpoint.latitude,
                            checkpoint.longitude,
                            location.latitude,
                            location.longitude, results)
                        val distance = results[0]
                        Log.d("Distance: ", distance.toString())
                        if (distance <= 15) {
                            //stopLocationUpdates()
                            val i = Intent(this@MapActivity, ExerciseActivity::class.java)
                            i.putExtra("exerciseId", checkpoint.exercise.exerciseId)
                            startActivity(i)
                            finish()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.getMainLooper())
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    startLocationUpdates()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    stopLocationUpdates()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    stopLocationUpdates()
}

private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `startLocationUpdates()` call inside `onCreate()` and I hope it will get you to work.

**Explenation:**
You are calling `startLocationUpdates()` method in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods. So it will make two callbacks which you store the latest inside `locationCallback`. But you loose the first callback created when `onCreate()` is called. So when you call `fusedLocationClient .removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)`, you just remove one of the callbacks!

Comment: They can also remove the redundant removal in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did work, however it is taking more than 10s to update the location, although I have  `locationRequest.interval = 300` and `locationRequest.fastestInterval = 100` . Any idea why?

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems its the initial delay which android has to locate first location. But after that it would be updated as interval you've set.